# How to search the group by the DisplayName using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to [the document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list), I can list the Office 365 Groups by using the following Graph API:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups`

I have a C# Web application, and there is a input for searching by the Group DisplayName. Any idea how to query groups based on the DisplayName?

I have tried the following URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Test"` in the MS Graph Explorer which didn't work.

I get the following error.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "This query is not supported.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "35d90412-03f3-44e7-a7a4-d33cee155101",
        "date": "2018-10-25T05:32:53"
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to search the Group by the `DisplayName` using the search parameters.

Based on [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter), we can currently search only message and person collections. So we couldn't use the search parameter.

We can use the filter query parameter to search the Group by DisplayName. For example, we can search the groups whose displayName is start with 'Test',the request url like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Test')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is so dumb. The number one use case of retrieving groups for a user is to look for certain groups, and there is 0 filter capability.

Answer (score 7):

#### UPDATE

I see that the answer has already been accepted, but I came across the same issue and found that this answer is out of date. For the next person, this is the **update**:

The 'search' functionality does work. Whether it was fixed along the way or always has, I am not sure.

- 'groups' support search,
- both the v1 and beta api support search,
- search only works on 'displayName' and 'description' fields,
- searching on 'directory objects' require a special header: 'ConsistencyLevel: eventual'

Point number 4 is what tripped me up!

#### Your request would look like this:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Test"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search=%22displayName:Test%22)

With the request header:
*ConsistencyLevel: eventual*

Comment: Ditto^^. And it looks like MS has made some improvements to the error returned from the response.  I got the following when trying it in the Graph Explorer.
{..."message": "Request with $search query parameter only works through MSGraph with a special request header: 'ConsistencyLevel: eventual'"...}

Answer (score 6):

Here is C# code that I wrote to get a group using the DisplayName.  This code requires a reference to the OfficeDevPnP.Core.

```
private static async Task<Group> GetGroupByName(string accessToken, string groupName)
        {
            var graphClient = GraphUtility.CreateGraphClient(accessToken);

            var targetGroupCollection = await graphClient.Groups.Request()
                                        .Filter($"startsWith(displayName,'{groupName}')")
                                        .GetAsync();

            var targetGroup = targetGroupCollection.ToList().Where(g => g.DisplayName == groupName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (targetGroup != null)
                return targetGroup;

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another catch: You can only specify the first 21 characters and the search always uses 'startsWith'. You're out of luck if you specify more than that: The search always fails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).